# Error update Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

When I tried to upgrade Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 the errors below appeared:

```
Reading package lists... Done

W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com raring Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2**
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release**  
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.**

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  # point of no return
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that dist-upgrade is just updating all your packages. Bit of a misnomer.

### Give [this](http://lawrit.lawr.ucdavis.edu/it-help-center/how-to/upgrading-ubuntu-via-command-line) a try!

In a nutshell, run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to update all packages, then

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

to do the actual update to 13.10

#### Otherwise,

Get your files out (using a Live USB/CD)
and reinstall from a 13.10 Live USB/CD.

If I helped please upvote/choose answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

after updating the sources list again. And reply weather it worked or not

Comment: tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/libproxy1-plugin-gsettings_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_i386.deb 
Size mismatch 
Failed to fetch 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_i386.deb 
Size mismatch 
Failed to fetch 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/libproxy1_0.4.11-0ubuntu4_i386.deb 
Size mismatch 
Restoring original system state
Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Comment: still not working